# WHERE Col1 IN CASE WHEN someCondition THEN ('a', 'b') ELSE ('c', 'd') END

Tags: sql, t-sql

Got a simple question.  This is apparently not valid T-SQL syntax:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Col2 IN
    CASE WHEN someCondition THEN
        ('a', 'b')
    ELSE
        ('c', 'd')
    END
```

Doing some real simple things, like surrounding the `CASE WHEN...END` block in parentheses, adding `SELECT` keywords, cutting and pasting `Col2 IN` into each of the case handlers, etc. hasn't quite panned out too well.  Honestly this looks like it should just work, but `CASE` statements can run into some awkward restrictions in SQL.

What's wrong with this syntax, and how can it be fixed?  Is there any real reason the above syntax is broken (possibly leading to a small tweak that will fix the above), or is this just something that the language designers arbitrarily "forgot" to handle (probably requiring a fairly different approach than the above)?

Note that some applications of this would involve `someCondition` taking the following form:

```
(SELECT SomeCol FROM OtherTable WHERE id = n) = 'someVal'
```

I'm not sure whether duplicating that sort of subselect and comparison within the same query is liable to cause it to actually get called separately in each spot in SQL, but even if it's only called as many times as without duplication, it still feels bad writing it twice.  It could be run once and stored in a variable, I suppose, but that's also extra code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a `CASE` must be a *single* value.

The RHS of `IN` can be the result of a `SELECT`, hence you could do something like:

```
declare @Which as Int = 0;
select *
  from ( values ( 0 ), ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 4 ), ( 5 ) ) as Things( Thing )
  where Thing in (
    select * from ( values ( 1 ), ( 2 ) ) as Bar( Foo ) where @Which = 0
    union
    select * from ( values ( 3 ), ( 4 ) ) as Bar( Foo ) where @Which = 1 )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Col1
FROM SomeTable
WHERE
    ( someCondition and Col2 in ('a','b') ) or ( not someCondition and Col2 in ('c','d') )
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `where` logic to eliminate the `case`:

```
where (( someCondition ) and Col2 in ('a', 'b')) or
      (not ( someCondition) and Col2 in ('c', 'd') )
```

(This version assumes that `someCondition` is never `NULL`.)